# Grafana Loki search from variables

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, grafana-variable

There is a dashboard in grafana created in Loki. The "Services logs" row has one panel that expands depending on the selected containers in the "service_to_display" filter. I need to make it so that the search occurs only in the panel in which the service_name is identical to the one selected in the "service_for_search" filter using the Text Box variable. At the moment the request looks like this `{container_name=~"$service_to_display", level=~"$level", host=~"$host"} | logfmt | (container_name =~ "$service_for_search") |= "$search_for_service"` .
But in this case, the logs are displayed only in one panel.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjnTv.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrUZL.png)